# submit button in a table

Tags: jquery, html

I dont want to use forms.
I want to have a submit button and send some information on submitting  a button.

```
<div id="tab" >
<table>
       <td>Num</th>
       <tr>Name </th>
       </td>
       <td> <tr>  Num</td>
       <tr>Name2 </th>
       </td>

</table>

 <input type="submit" id="mysubmit1" Value="Submit this" />
</div>

<script>
$('#tab').submit(function(e) {  
    //some code here.
}  
</script>
```

I am having issue in getting the submit button get the reference so that I can get all the content.
I tried div.tab  also. am I missing anything in this context

Comment: what are you really trying to do? are you trying to send all the the table data?

Comment: yes. I am having issue with form so want to use Table and send the data. so while trying to access I am getting this isse

Comment: Why would you want to send the table data if you already have it? Are you embedding input elements in a table?

Comment: I have a table with data . I am planning to send it using Post. I really dont want to use forms. that said, I a trying to use jquery-submit

Comment: Maybe you should start by fixing your HTML. You seem to have a bunch of mismatched tags.

Comment: Do you want to send table data to another page, you can use jquery ajax to send all data into post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try something like

```
<input type="button" id="mysubmit1" Value="Submit this" onclick="javascript:myfun()" />
```

Then create `function` using `javascript`

```
<script language="javascript">
function myfun(){
//do your work
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try correcting the node tags(tr, td) in your table first as below. **It's highly disorganized.**

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>Num</td>
   <td>Name </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Num</td>
   <td>Name2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the below.
​

```
​$('#mysubmit1').on('click',function(){
     $('#tab').submit();
});​​​​​​​​​​​


 $('#tab').submit(function() {
       alert('Submitted');
      return false;
 });
```

​

Answer (score 0):

To send information that isn't entered by the user, you can still use forms using input elements with the type attribute set to hidden e.g.,

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="field" type="hidden" value="<the data you want to send>" />
</form>
```

Then you can process the resulting post request normally

Comment: With the type attribute set to true?  I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: I dont want to use forms at all. I have many issusing using the "preventdefault"

Comment: @TheLearner that's a new problem, but what's wrong with 

`<input type="submit" id="submit" />` 

`$("#submit").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`